# Nativescript: adding a run script phase

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

Hi I am developing a plugin to wrap around AppDynamics.

I need to do the following from this documentation https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO45/Upload+the+dSYM+File

```
In Xcode, select your project from the Project Navigator.
Click on the application target.
Select the Build Phase tab in the Settings editor.
Click the + icon in the upper left corner of the main panel.
Select New Run Script Phase from the dropdown.
In the script box, add the following lines:

export ADRUM_ACCOUNT_NAME="<Account_Name_HERE>" // From the View License - End User Monitoring section of the License Page
export ADRUM_LICENSE_KEY="<License_Key_HERE>"  // From the View License - End User Monitoring section of the License Page
SCRIPT=$(/usr/bin/find "${SRCROOT}" -name xcode_build_dsym_upload.sh | head -n 1)
/bin/sh "${SCRIPT}"
```

however since the platform files are regenerated each time, can I do this through hooks? The `xcode_build_dsym_upload.sh` is part of the podFile and when I try with hooks (which i think is before the xCode build) I'm getting a `no file or directory found` error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it can be done through hooks. May be referring the hooks from [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/) might help you, it has similar scripts to be injected for uploading dSYM file for crashlytics.

Comment: Thanks. that is exactly what i was looking for !